# Stochastic process integration - Notation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

I'm facing with a problem of notation and I hope stack could help me!

Let $X(t)$ be a time-continuous stochastic process, with pdf $p_X(x, t)$.
Let $g(x, t)$ be a generic function. 
Now, consider the following:

$$ Y(t) = \int_{0}^{t} g(X(s),s)dX(s)$$
where $Y(t)$ is itself a time-continuous stochastic process.
In which way I must interpret/deal with this integral?

I mean, how do I perform the integration, since integration domain is over time while I only have $dX(t)$?

I feel like I'm missing something, and most likely I must perform a "change of variable" by using the pdf $p_X(x, t)$.

Can someone bring me some light?

Comment: The LHS cannot be a function of $t$. Do you mean $Y(t_2)$? Likewise, $g(X,t)$ makes no sense. Do you mean $g(X(t),t)$?

Comment: thanks for the advice, I corrected it.

Comment: Still `g(X,s)` is mysterious.

Comment: @did: Well, implicitely, $g(X,s) = g(X(s), s)$. I think that it is clear from the context and I don't understand the downvote

Comment: Your identity is finally correct, this is nice. (In case your last comment implies that I downvoted your question, please note that: (1.) you have no way of knowing this, (2.) I did not downvote, (3.) I do resent very much having had to say that I did not.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [stochastic integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C5%8D_calculus). In order to grasp the notion, I think it is a good idea to follow a whole course on that subject, maybe even a broader course on stochastic processes in continuous time and martingales.

I recommend Kuo's [stochastic integration textbook](http://books.google.com/books/about/Introduction_to_Stochastic_Integration.html?id=VEAxuzpCvj0C) for an introduction specifically targetting such integrals. There's also Øksendal's [Stochastic differential equations textbook](http://books.google.com/books/about/Stochastic_Differential_Equations.html?id=kXw9hB4EEpUC). The first chapter of Kuo's book has a very nice pedagogical explanation of the heuristics of that integral.

---

As an extra bonus, I also noticed that Mörters and Peres' book on Brownian motion is available online on Mörters webpage at this [link](http://people.bath.ac.uk/maspm/book.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Since I'm quite expert on time-discrete stochastic process, I was wondering that dealing with the time-continuous counterpart was a little bit similar.

Comment: It is much more complicated in continuous time.

Comment: Got it. There exists more handy reference (like a review paper or a didactic pdf)  about that?

Comment: There are these lecture notes http://people.bath.ac.uk/maspm/stoa.ps but I feel they are not as pedagogical as the the references above. I really recommend studying one of the books because there are a lot of pitfalls and I find the topic hard when beginning.